# C# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am learning C# and am using Visual Studio 2010 to build a payroll program. I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'".

My code is :

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get service instance
                var employerPeriodService = Program.Kernel.Get<IEmployerPeriodService>();

                // Get new code
                var newCode = employerPeriodService.GenerateSAPCode();

                // Create object
                var employerPeriodAdd =
                    new EmployerPeriod
                    {
                        Code = newCode,
                        Name = newCode,
                        U_Tax_year = int.Parse(cb_tax_year.Text),
                        //U_Day_hrs = cb_number_hours.Text,
                        //U_Week_days = cb_number_days_week.Text,
                        //U_Week_hrs = txt_number_hours_week.Text,
                        //U_Month_days = cb_number_days_month.Text,
                        //U_Month_hrs = txt_number_hours_month.Text,
                        //U_Fortnight_days = cb_number_days_fortnight.Text,
                        //U_Fortnight_hrs = txt_number_hours_fortnight.Text,
                        //U_Weeks_in_month = cb_avg_weeks_month.Text,
                        //U_No_of_Fortnights = cb_avg_fortnights_month.Text,
                        U_Starting_period = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text),
                        U_Ending_period = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text)

                        //U_Comments = txt_comments.Text
                    };

                // Save record
                employerPeriodService.AddEmployerPeriod(employerPeriodAdd);

                MessageBox.Show("Employer Payroll Period Added Successfully. Intake Ref: " + newCode.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            catch (RulesException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.GetErrorMessages(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
```

In Microsoft SQL Server where my database is, U_Tax_year is defined as smallint. What do I need to do to solve this error. Do I convert what I get from the combo box 'cb_tax_year.Text' to int and how do I achieve this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried short.Parse instead of int.Parse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it's as simple as changing this:

```
U_Tax_year = int.Parse(cb_tax_year.Text),
```

to this:

```
U_Tax_year = short.Parse(cb_tax_year.Text),
```

Basically you should check the type of the `U_Tax_year` property and make sure you parse the text appropriately so that the result of the RHS of the = sign is assignment-compatible with the property type.

Comment: Thanks. I thought an int was an int whether short int or long int. Solved.

Answer (score 4):

SQLServer's `smallint` is the equivalent of c#'s `short`. so try `short.Parse()` instead of `int.Parse()`

Answer (score 3):

Use short.Parse rather than int.Parse